# Can you retrieve a change from the index?

Tags: git

I ask only for my general Git education - I don't have any particular problem atm. I'm just curious. Say you do this:

```
vim foo.txt
```

...write some good doco...

```
git add foo.txt
rm foo.txt
```

Can it be retrieved? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git checkout -- foo.txt`

`git checkout`, when given a path, checks things out of the index (by default; it can be instructed to check things out from commits as well).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the worspace file back by:

```
git checkout foo.txt
```